# Convert .json to ipynb

Tags: json, jupyter-notebook

I am taking a course that uses ipython notebook. When I try to download the notebook (through File -> Download as -> ipython notebook), I get a file that ends with ".ipynb.json". It doesn't open as an ipython notebook but as a .json file so something like this:

```
{
 "cells": [
  {
   "cell_type": "markdown",
   "metadata": {},
   "source": [
    "---\n",
    "\n",
    "_You are currently looking at **version 1.1** of this notebook. To         download notebooks and datafiles, as well as get help on Jupyter notebooks in the Coursera platform, visit the [Jupyter Notebook FAQ](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/resources/0dhYG) course resource._\n",
    "\n",
    "---"
   ]
  },
...
}
```

I've tried deleting the ".json" in the file name and it doesn't work. How can I convert this file back to something that can be opened and run as an ipython notebook? Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like you are just trying to open a notebook correct?  If so run jupyter first.  When the dashboard opens as new browser tab, search for the notebook in the directory tree.  Then just click on the notebook name.

Comment: I did that but it opens as shown in my question, not the normal look of a notebook.

Comment: The file you downloaded is a json file which captures the notebook - like a save file.  You probably want to download it as HTML so the rendered version opens in your browser.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

My Solution: just remove the filename extension **.json**. for example, change **myfile.ipynb.json** to **myfile.ipynb**. Then, you can open it by a click in jupyter notebook !

I have encounter the same problem as you did. I found a link that describe what ipynb exactly is. see here http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/rel-1.0.0/interactive/nbconvert.html. It says ipynb file is actually json file. Hope this

Comment: Yes, a Jupyter Notebook file is just a JSON-encoded file.

Answer (score 7):

On the Mac you could go and

1. Right click on the `filename.ipynb.json`
2. Click on `Get Info` from the list.
3. From the `Get Info` window, find the section `Name&Extension` remove the    extension/suffix  `.json` from the file name.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Are you trying download this from Github? Especially on Google Chrome browsers, I've had issues download .ipynb files using right click > **Save link as...** I'm not sure if other browsers have this issue (Microsoft Edge, Mozilla Firefox, Safari, etc.).

This causes issues since when downloading, it doesn't completely download the file usually and it becomes corrupted so you can't download an IPython notebook that may run properly. One trick when trying to download .ipynb files on Github is to click it, click **Raw**, then copy everything (Ctrl + A) and paste it into a blank file (using text editors such as Notepad, Notepad++, Vim, etc.) and save it as "whatever_file_name_you_choose.ipynb". Then you should be able to properly run this file, assuming a non-corrupted file was uploaded to Github.

A lot of people with very large, complicated IPython notebooks on Github will inevitably run into this issue when simply trying to download with **Save link as...**. Hopefully this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I opened it as/with nbviewer and then selected it all and saved it as a "txt" file that I then opened in Notepad++. I then resaved it as a file with the extension ipynb and opened it in my jupyter notebook ok.

Answer (score 1):

The easy thing to do is to copy the JSON contents into a notepad and save it again with .ipynb extension

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the `.json` file extension leaving the `.ipynb` one, as pointed out by the following related post: https://superuser.com/questions/1497243/why-cant-i-save-a-jupyter-notebook-as-a-ipynb. As @jackie already said, you should consider them as `.json` files meant only to be edited by the IPython Notebook app itself, not for hand-editing.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple trick. Let that file get downloaded automatically. Re-download it again then it will prompt you to download and replace that file. At that time, you save that by replacing .json to .ipynb

Answer (score 0):

After downloading the file with ipynb.json, Take the following steps:

1. Go your terminal/command line window
2. Navigate to the directory where your file is
3. Type:
   windows OS: rename yourfile.ipynb.json to yourfile.ipynb
   Unix/Linux: mv yourfile.ipynb.json to yourfile.ipynb

This work perfectly for me.

Answer (score -2):

i tried this method and it worked. Just copy, paste it in notepad and save as "file_name.ipynb". hope this works for you too.